# Движение картинки по экрану

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Создаю интернет магазин, видел на одном сайте как при нажатии на кнопку "положить в корзину" создавался эффект как товар улетал в корзину, в верхний правый угол.
Очень удобная штука, пользователь сразу видит, что товар кладётся в корзину.
Весь инет перерыл не могу найти готовое решение, может здесь дадите намётку?

Answer (score 3):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#basket{position:absolute;top:20px;right:30px;border:1px #000 solid;width:200px;height:200px}
#goods{position:absolute;top:600px;left:300px}
#goods div, #basket div{border:1px #000 solid;width:50px;height:50px;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer}
#goods div.el1, #basket div.el1{background:#f00}
#goods div.el2, #basket div.el2{background:#0f0}
#goods div.el3, #basket div.el3{background:#00f}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="basket">basket<br /></div>
<div id="goods">
    <div class="el1">tovar1</div>
    <div class="el2">tovar2</div>
    <div class="el3">tovar3</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#goods div').live('click', function(){
        var t = $(this), e = t.clone(), b = $('#basket'), o = t.position(), po = t.parent().offset(), bo = b.offset();
        e.css({top: o.top+'px', left: o.left+'px', position: 'absolute'});
        t.parent().append(e);
        e.animate({top: -po.top+bo.top+(b.height()-t.height())/2, left: -po.left+bo.left+(b.width()-t.width())/2}, 500, function(){
            $(this).css({left: 0, top: 0, position: 'static'}).appendTo(b);
        });
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Можно и короче, но общий смысл понятен. Используется jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Поколупай jQuery, в нем много функций для "красивостей", авось что и подойдет :) Есть хорошая функция animate(), но я не уверен, работает ли она с картинками (вроде нельзя делать ресайз).

Comment: Всё там работает, и с картинками, и ресайз. Именно эту функцию и нужно использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, не весь инет перерыли :)
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager

Comment: Действительно )

Comment: Хотя, не совсем то, что мне надо.
Там было видно движение картинки, эффект как будто товар улетает в карзину, а тут из одного места исчезает в другом появляется. Конечно на безрыбье и рак рыба, и все же спасибо )

Comment: Я дал линк, там все это есть, в jquery все это есть.

Answer (score 0):

А нельзя просто координаты менять и счетчик со стопом поставить..? Можно через тот же Jquery.

Comment: Да конечно можно, но я это ниразу не делал, а это значит все сделать самому. Я не могу назвать себя леньтяем, но мне хотелось бы готовое решение. Уж не критикуйте меня сильно )