# Добавление эффекта к корзине на jquery

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, есть корзина работает на ajax+jquery. Хочу добавить эффект, моя функция срабатывает при клике, нужно чтобы создался клон картинки товара и летел в указанное место, укажите в какое направление двигаться.

Comment: В сторону корзины разумеется! :D

Comment: Туда и собираюсь : ) только вот направление где прописать : ) пример бы какой нибуть

Comment: Вам алгоритм движения нужен или что?

Answer (score 1):

[Движение картинки по экрану](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/15247/%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%83)